# Interacting Chiral topological invariants using Green function

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

We can calculate the topological invariants for 1D **interacting topological insulators**  as

$n=\frac{\text{Tr}}{2\pi i}\oint_cG\partial_kG^{-1} $

where as for **interacting chiral topological insulators** we can calculate topological invariant using

$n=\frac{\text{Tr}}{2\pi i}\oint_c\Sigma G\partial_kG^{-1}$

where $\Sigma$ is chiral symmetry matrix
Why we are here multiplying by chiral symmetry matrix $\Sigma$ in second equation to calculate invariant ? what is the physical reason behind it?

Comment: Would be interesting if you could provide reference for the expressions you gave for the topological invariants. Thanks in advance.